# Android App with Material Design theme crashes on Android 5 and 6

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-theme, material-components-android

I created my own application, which is made using Material Design and tested it on Android 10 and 11, as well as on Android 5 and 6. On Android 10 and 11 there are no problems, but on Android 5 and 6 the application crashes with the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.suslanium.encryptor, PID: 10710
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.suslanium.encryptor/com.suslanium.encryptor.PasswordActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2583)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:843)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
    at com.suslanium.encryptor.PasswordActivity.onCreate(PasswordActivity.java:40)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6309)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2530)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

This app uses a theme that inherits from Material Design theme. Oddly enough, the application worked fine with the Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar theme before.

night\themes.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Encryptor.Dark" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#37474F</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#263238</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">#90A4AE</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">#607D8B</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#171E21</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">#171E21</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.Encryptor.Toolbar.Dark</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/UbuntuTextStyle</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/UbuntuMatButtonStyleDark</item>
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/UbuntuTextInputStyleDark</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/UbuntuButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/snackBarButtonDark</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#171E21</item>
    <item name="android:switchTextAppearance">@style/SwitchTextAppearanceDark</item>
    <item name="switchTextAppearance">@style/SwitchTextAppearanceDark</item>
    <item name="navigationViewBackgroundColor">@color/navDark</item>
    <item name="navSelectedItemTextColor">@color/navTextDark</item>
    <item name="navTitleColor">@color/navTextDark</item>
    <item name="dialogButtonColor">@color/dialogButtonDark</item>
    <item name="dialogTitleColor">@color/dialogTitleDark</item>
    <item name="bottomBarColor">@color/bottomBarDark</item>
    <item name="titleColor">@color/titleColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="inputColor">@color/bottomBarDark</item>
    <item name="explorerIconColor">@color/explorerIconsDark</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
</style>
<style name="Widget.Encryptor.Toolbar.Dark" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <item name="titleTextColor">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextColor">#CFD8DC</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.Encryptor.Dark.Nav">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#607D8B</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.Encryptor.Dark.ActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#37474F</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#263238</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">#90A4AE</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">#607D8B</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#171E21</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">#171E21</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.Encryptor.Toolbar.Dark</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/UbuntuTextStyle</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/UbuntuMatButtonStyleDark</item>
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/UbuntuTextInputStyleDark</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/UbuntuButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/snackBarButtonDark</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#171E21</item>
    <item name="navigationViewBackgroundColor">@color/navDark</item>
    <item name="navSelectedItemTextColor">@color/navTextDark</item>
    <item name="dialogButtonColor">@color/dialogButtonDark</item>
    <item name="dialogTitleColor">@color/dialogTitleDark</item>
    <item name="bottomBarColor">@color/bottomBarDark</item>
    <item name="titleColor">@color/titleColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="explorerIconColor">@color/explorerIconsDark</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="inputColor">@color/bottomBarDark</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="Theme.Encryptor.Dark.Pass" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#37474F</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#171E21</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">#90A4AE</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">#607D8B</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#171E21</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">#171E21</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.Encryptor.Toolbar.Dark</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/UbuntuTextStyle</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/UbuntuMatButtonStyleDark</item>
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/UbuntuTextInputStyleDark</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/UbuntuButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/snackBarButtonDark</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#171E21</item>
    <item name="android:switchTextAppearance">@style/SwitchTextAppearanceDark</item>
    <item name="switchTextAppearance">@style/SwitchTextAppearanceDark</item>
    <item name="navigationViewBackgroundColor">@color/navDark</item>
    <item name="navSelectedItemTextColor">@color/navTextDark</item>
    <item name="dialogButtonColor">@color/dialogButtonDark</item>
    <item name="dialogTitleColor">@color/dialogTitleDark</item>
    <item name="bottomBarColor">@color/bottomBarDark</item>
    <item name="titleColor">@color/titleColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="inputColor">@color/bottomBarDark</item>
    <item name="explorerIconColor">@color/explorerIconsDark</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Nav">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">10dp</item>
</style>
<style name="MaterialAlertDialog_rounded" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/DialogCorners</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/UbuntuAppearance</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/UbuntuAppearanceTitle</item>
</style>
<style name="DialogCorners">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">16dp</item>
</style>
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/dialogButtonColor</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ubuntu</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">#00000000</item>
</style>
<style name="UbuntuTextStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ubuntu</item>
</style>
<style name="UbuntuButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ubuntu</item>
</style>
<style name="UbuntuEditTextStyle" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ubuntu</item>
</style>
<style name="UbuntuMatButtonStyleDark" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">#90A4AE</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ubuntu</item>
</style>
<style name="UbuntuTextInputStyleDark" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <!-- The color of the label when it is collapsed and the text field is active -->
    <item name="hintTextColor">#CFD8DC</item>
    <!-- The color of the label in all other text field states (such as resting and disabled) -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">#CFD8DC</item>
</style>
<style name="UbuntuTextInputStyleDarkWelcome" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <!-- The color of the label when it is collapsed and the text field is active -->
    <item name="hintTextColor">?attr/inputColor</item>
    <!-- The color of the label in all other text field states (such as resting and disabled) -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">?attr/inputColor</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">?attr/inputColor</item>
</style>
<style name="EditTextDark" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/ubuntu</item>
</style>
<style name="snackBarButtonDark" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar">
    <item name="backgroundTint">#00000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#37474F</item>
</style>
<style name="snackBarButtonLight" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar">
    <item name="backgroundTint">#00000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#CFD8DC</item>
</style>
<style name="UbuntuAppearance">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/ubuntu</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ubuntu</item>
</style>
<style name="SwitchTextAppearanceDark" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">#CFD8DC</item>
</style>
<style name="UbuntuTextStyleNav">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ubuntu_medium</item>
</style>
<style name="UbuntuAppearanceTitle" parent="@style/MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/ubuntu</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ubuntu</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/dialogTitleColor</item>
</style>
<style name="UbuntuTextInputStyleLight" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <!-- The color of the label when it is collapsed and the text field is active -->
    <item name="hintTextColor">#37474F</item>
    <!-- The color of the label in all other text field states (such as resting and disabled) -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#37474F</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">#37474F</item>
</style>
```

Theme.Encryptor.Dark is default in my app. This theme has some custom color attributes. And also, all layouts in my app cannot be viewed in Android Studio with my theme because every Material component gives this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
```

Also every layout gives me "Missing Styles" error. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

My app is working now, but this issue still persists. My app is working on some devices with light theme, but crashes with dark theme for some reason.

themes.xml(light theme):

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Encryptor.Light" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#78909C</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#607D8B</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">#B0BEC5</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">#90A4AE</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#455A64</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#455A64</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.Encryptor.Toolbar.Light</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/UbuntuTextStyle</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/UbuntuMatButtonStyleDark</item>
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/UbuntuTextInputStyleLight</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/UbuntuButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/snackBarButtonLight</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="navigationViewBackgroundColor">@color/navLight</item>
    <item name="navSelectedItemTextColor">@color/navTextLight</item>
    <item name="navTitleColor">@color/navTitleLight</item>
    <item name="dialogButtonColor">@color/dialogButtonLight</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#607D8B</item>
    <item name="dialogTitleColor">@color/dialogTitleLight</item>
    <item name="bottomBarColor">@color/bottomBarLight</item>
    <item name="titleColor">@color/titleColorLight</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="inputColor">@color/navTextDark</item>
    <item name="explorerIconColor">@color/explorerIconsLight</item>
    <item name="android:switchTextAppearance">@style/SwitchTextAppearanceDark</item>
    <item name="switchTextAppearance">@style/SwitchTextAppearanceDark</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="Theme.Encryptor.Light.ActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#78909C</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#607D8B</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">#B0BEC5</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">#90A4AE</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#455A64</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#455A64</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.Encryptor.Toolbar.Light</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/UbuntuTextStyle</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/UbuntuMatButtonStyleDark</item>
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/UbuntuTextInputStyleLight</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/UbuntuButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/snackBarButtonLight</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/navLight</item>
    <item name="navSelectedItemTextColor">@color/navTextLight</item>
    <item name="dialogButtonColor">@color/dialogButtonLight</item>
    <item name="dialogTitleColor">@color/dialogTitleLight</item>
    <item name="bottomBarColor">@color/bottomBarLight</item>
    <item name="titleColor">@color/titleColorLight</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#607D8B</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="inputColor">@color/navTextDark</item>
    <item name="explorerIconColor">@color/explorerIconsLight</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FF00B7FF</item>
</style>

<style name="NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Encryptor.Toolbar.Light" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <item name="titleTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
<style name="Ubuntu" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ubuntu_medium</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.Encryptor.Light.Pass" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#78909C</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">#B0BEC5</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">#90A4AE</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#37474F</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#37474F</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.Encryptor.Toolbar.Light</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/UbuntuTextStyle</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/UbuntuMatButtonStyleDark</item>
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/UbuntuTextInputStyleLight</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/UbuntuButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#607D8B</item>
    <item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/snackBarButtonLight</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#CFD8DC</item>
    <item name="navigationViewBackgroundColor">@color/navLight</item>
    <item name="navSelectedItemTextColor">@color/navTextLight</item>
    <item name="dialogButtonColor">@color/dialogButtonLight</item>
    <item name="dialogTitleColor">@color/dialogTitleLight</item>
    <item name="bottomBarColor">@color/bottomBarLight</item>
    <item name="titleColor">@color/titleColorLight</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="inputColor">@color/navTextDark</item>
    <item name="explorerIconColor">@color/explorerIconsLight</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Both styles are almost same(in general), but only light theme works on some devices.

Comment: Is there anything unusual about `PasswordActivity` compared to your app's launcher activity, such as theme or base class that you extend?

Comment: @CommonsWare PasswordActivity extends from AppCompatActivity and it is a launcher activity that uses default theme.

Comment: Does your activity display a dialog ?

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI No, it doesn't.